# How to search one word in Firefox address bar with Google, not OpenDNS?

Tags: firefox-for-android, search

When I search only *one word* (which isn't URL) in address bar, Firefox treats it as URL and `Website Unavailable` notification is displayed with OpenDNS search page. How to replace OpenDNS with Google here?

Comment: Good thing is that this behavior is going away soon. OpenDNS Guide (which intercepts unresolved names that cause this issue) is now [deprecated](https://www.opendns.com/no-more-ads/). OpenDNS would no longer redirect to the OpenDNS Guide search page when you type in a single word in the address bar, which means that upon receiving domain name resolution failure, Firefox will redirect you to your preferred search page.